# I want to implement calender in header level of editable table in prime ng

Tags: calendar, header, primeng

Primeng Editable Table Header Calender

if i select some date in header calender it should be implemented in the below rows of selected data in editable table

i m not getting any clue to implement this. i want the same date should be selected in the below row data whatever date is given in header level calender